# php ldap_search get extended attributes

Tags: php

I wrote following code to get AD attributes using php

```
$base_dn = 'OU=User_Accounts,DC=test,DC=local';
$filter = "(givenname=*$accountName*)";
$attributes = array();
$attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
$attributes[] = 'givenname';
$attributes[] = 'sn';
$attributes[] = 'userAccountControl';
$attributes[] = 'ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion';
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $base_dn, $filter, $attributes);

$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
    $jsonArray[$x]['samaccountname'] = $entries[$x]["samaccountname"][0];
    $jsonArray[$x]['givenname'] = $entries[$x]["givenname"][0];
    $jsonArray[$x]['surname'] = $entries[$x]["sn"][0];
    $jsonArray[$x]['isenabled'] = $entries[$x]["userAccountControl"][0];
    $jsonArray[$x]['ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion'] = $entries[$x]["ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion"][0];
}
```

Using above code, I can get the user's `samaccountname`, `givenname` and `surname`, but `userAccountControl` and `ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` are returning null values.

Can someone please advise how I can get those values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that `userAccountControl` and `ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` are actually present in the request as you expect?

Comment: Just checked and I get the error message as `PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userAccountControl` in logs.. How can I verify that these are actually present in the request?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is simply that your requests (i.e. `$entries[$x]`) simply don't have the data that you expect (i.e. the `userAccountControl` and `ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` fields). To definitively diagnose this, I would try running it through a remote debugger to figure out what data is present and what data isn't. If you can't run it through a remote debugger, you may need to add logging so that you can conclusively prove whether or not the data is present in a production environment.

Comment: Hi @entpnerd, you are right.. There is no data for those fields. Can you please advise, how can I get that data, as all users have both parameters set in AD. PS. for `ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` its "true" or "false" and for `userAccountControl` its 512 or 514

Comment: I don't think that it's as much of a programming problem as it is an integration issue. From what I gather, when you call `ldap_search()`, the returned `$result` just doesn't have the expected data. I would work with whoever serves that data to determine why they aren't populating the right fields. That being said, it is plausible that `ldap_get_entries()` is at fault and while `$result` contains the right data, it's the mapping logic in `ldap_get_entries()` that produces `$entries` which is at fault. Do you know whether the problem is in `$result` or `$entries`?

Comment: No, I am not sure whether the problem is in `$result` or `$entries`. However, I think it must be at `$entries`, because all 3 attributes are working and 2 aren't.

Comment: That's unfortunate. All I can say is to work with your downstream service owners and try to remote debug and log as much as you can to diagnose the issue.